# What are some ways to produce a pre-determined sequence of a large number of dice rolls?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

What are some ways to produce a pre-determined sequence of a large number of dice rolls (on the order of 100-1000 times) using biased dice or a biased human roller given the constraints that multiple dice (more than 2) have to be projected in one go from a height of at least 1 meter onto a transparent (acrylic/glass) platform? I'm looking for potential security concerns for [a proposed method to generate a publicly verifiable random seed](https://gist.github.com/vinamrsachdeva/c5cf6d0def5738aa1ff400373e32d0f4). If an attack vector can get one to be sure of a narrow set of possible outcomes (in lower 1000s), it could potentially harm the security of the system.

Answer (score 1):

The concerns aren't well founded - sure, there is a possibility to produce a robot precise enough and with algorithms so advanced it could land the dice on the desired side every time. It would be impossible to make it unconspicuous though - the precision would need to be exceptional, and so it wouldn't pass muster.

Thing is, the device can be made arbitrarily complex, but it can just as well be made very simple - and so the requirements should demand it is made very simple.

All you need to assure the machine will produce good randomness is to require it's sloppy enough. Simple "budget" off-the-shelf hardware, hobby class materials, some baffles in the dice path to introduce extra tumble, primitive controls (at most simple 8-bit microcontroller, preferably not even that, just some mechanical switches), only minimum of most rudimentary sensors (if any) critical to the operation. And construction primitive enough even most rudimentary engineering background is enough to determine how it works and verify it works "poorly enough". The current and near-future technology is way insufficient to allow disguising or hiding the ultra-precise cheating thrower parts within that.

"Compromised human roller" is really not a concern. At 1 meter drop, making sure the dice roll and bounce, there's no-one able to toss them well enough. "Biased dice" are just that, biased - some numbers happen more often than others, but the results are still random. Except of course for dice weighted in such a way they always land on one side, which is far too obvious to fly.

Then there are hi-tech options for the dice. e-paper coating that would change the eyes depending on the sequence and landing position, gyroscopic control to assure landing the correct side down, all sorts of such sci-fi shenanigans on the brink of feasibility, providing the dice are opaque. Make them of clear material and make sure the inside can be checked for "foreign bodies" by interested parties, and you're fine.